# laravel can not "move()" file

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel `5.3`.
And I use `cropper` https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper  to crop image and then upload it  to back end via ajax.

```
$('#uploadAvatar').on('click', function (e) {

    $("#image").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('croppedImage', blob);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('/change-avatar') }}",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData
        }).done(function (response) {
            //...
        }).fail(function (data) {
            //...
        });
    });
});
```

the headers of ajax request is like this:
[image]

Laravel get the image and do something like this:

```
public function changeAvatar (Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->croppedImage;
    $input = array('image' => $file);
    $rules = array(
        'image' => 'image'
    );
    $validator = \Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        return \Response::json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ]);

    }

    $destinationPath = '/images/uploads/';
    $user=\Auth::user();
    $fileName = $user->id . '_' . time() . '.'.$file->clientExtension();
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    //dd($file);
    $user ->avatar = $destinationPath.$fileName;
    $user ->save();

    return \Response::json([
        'success'=>true,
        'avatar'=>asset($destinationPath.$fileName),
    ]);

}
```

In above method, the line `$file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);` not working.
Why is it?

Comment: try using $destinationPath= public_path()."/images/uploads/";...it might not be getting path to your local directory..

Comment: @RohitS Thanks,it's ok now.